# Decrease VS201X build / load time

Tags: visual-studio, solid-state-drive

Here is my conundrum.

On the project I work on I need to switch branches a few times a day, when I do my machine grinds to a halt, it makes me really unproductive for 10 minutes while Visual Studio reloads the solution.

Compilation time is really slow as well this is 2-5 minutes of coffee making time because my machine is totally unusable during this.

Now my work machine is no beast but it's no desk clerk POS either. High spec i5 with 8GB of ram. HDD is possibly a cheap junker.

Our solution have roughly 11K of files and it's going to keep growing.

**What can I do to speed things up?**

I was thinking SSD possibly 4GB more RAM, setup a RAM drive?

Any suggestions welcome, if I do go the SSD route, any suggestions what goes on the SSD and what not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off anti-virus
2. more ram
3. SSD

In that order

Answer (score 0):

An SSD is the way to go, disk read/write peformance for small files in random access pattern is most important to make Visual Studio build faster. So go shopping for an SSD but be careful to check some benchmarks to find a drive that has good performance for small files and random access read/writes.

I would recommend something like the Samsung 840 Pro or similar, Intel also has some drives with good performance.

Another thing about your solution is that the number of Projects has an impact on build performance. You should keep the number of output assemblies small and also make sure all the Projects are using one and the same output folder and then change all references between Projects to assembly references and make sure the copy local setting is set to false. This will improve build times dramatically as it eliminated lots of assembly copy operations.

Answer (score 0):

An SSD will make a huge difference, as will more RAM, but in the meantime if you have a second HDD around, try installing that and put the source on it. In the days before SSDs we found a huge improvement in build times and machine usability when the source disk was separate to the OS. When it was all on the same disk the whole machine ground to a halt on big builds, but on separate disks the machine became usable again even while building.